# jquery datepicker ui order of operations

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I made a jsfiddle as I don't know if I'll explain this well : http://jsfiddle.net/jrrbg/

Basically I want to select a date in the first input box and display it in the second one but with a date one week earlier.

```
<p>Match Date<br />
      <input name="seatt_expire" type="text" class="datepicker" id="seatt_expire" />
    </p>

<p>Opening Registration<br />
      <input name="seatt_start" type="text" class="datepicker" id="seatt_start" />
</p>

$(function() {

$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({

dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
firstDay: 1,
altField: "#seatt_start"
});


$( "#seatt_start" ).datepicker( "setDate", -7 );

});
```

It is currently taking the default date and setting it 7 days earlier instead of using the date in the first box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that `$( "#seatt_start" ).datepicker( "setDate", -7 );` sets the date to 7 days minus today, not the previous date, also it doesn't trigger anything when the date from `seatt_expire` changes, you should use the `onSelect` event.

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("#seatt_start").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});
    $("#seatt_expire").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        firstDay: 1,
        onSelect: function (prev_date) {
            prev = prev_date.split("-");
            var date = new Date(prev[2], prev[1] - 1, prev[0]);
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();
            var new_date = new Date(y, m, d - 7);
            $("#seatt_start").removeAttr("disabled").datepicker("setDate", new_date);
        }
    });
});
```

Here, the date from `seatt_expire` is substracted and then parsed to subtract the 7 days you want, and the date from `seatt_start` will change along every time, also I separated both datepicker declarations to avoid the same `onSelect` event to be applied to both fields...

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/4vx5p/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do it :[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/Nya2X/)

```
$("#seat-expire").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    firstDay: 1,
    onSelect:function(text,obj){
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        dateObject.setDate(obj.currentDay-7);
        $("#seat-start").datepicker("setDate",dateObject);
    }
});
```

If required same could be applied to `#seat-start` only in reverse :

```
$("#seat-start").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        firstDay: 1,
        // display expire date
        onSelect:function(text,obj){
            var dateObject = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
            dateObject.setDate(obj.currentDay+7);
            $("#seat-expire").datepicker("setDate",dateObject);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works fine except that I wanted it to go only one way because in theory the Match date would not change but the registration date could so I wouldn't want it to go the other way.